# jQuery- animate() only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some functionality on my web page to hide or show the side-menu. I have two divs, `#collapse-side-nav`, and `#expand-side-nav`. The way it is set up right now is that by default `#expand-side-nav's` style is set to `display:none;` . Then when the user clicks on the `collapse-side-nav` id the `side-nav` collapses and then `#expand-side-nav` gets displayed.

I noticed that the new #expand-side-nav's positioning needs to be further to the right and a little bit higher than `#collapse-side-nav's` div, and I wanted to achieve this with animations so that it looks sleek. My code is below. However, when I test this out in the browser the animation only works once.

```
$('#collapse-side-nav').click(function() {
    $('.side-nav').toggle(300);
    $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
    $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('#expand-side-nav').animate({
        'margin-left' : 34,
        'margin-top' : 2
     }, "slow");
    $('.container').animate({
        'padding-left' : 0
     }, "slow");
});
$('#expand-side-nav').click(function() {
    $('.side-nav').toggle(325);
    $('#expand-side-nav').css('display', 'none');
    $('#collapse-side-nav').css('display', 'inherit');
    $('.container').animate({
        'padding-left' : 200
    }, "slow");
});
```

**EDIT:** 
I will try and post a fiddle later today. I also tried incrimenting rather than declaring exact pixels ([jQuery- animate() only works once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578063/jquery-animate-only-works-once))
However this increments each and every time meaning the css will keep getting pushed further and further to the right every single time the user clicks on the div.

Comment: Post your HTML, or prepare a jsfiddle.

Comment: You have unnecessary commas in three lines in your code which could stop JS from executing again:  'padding-left' : 200, <- e.g. this one.

Comment: @SzybkiSasza I have gotten rid of the unnecessary commas in the animate. However the problem still persists. I have also updated the question to reflect those changes in my code.

Comment: When you try to animate again, the element already has the margins set at those values. You have to reset the margins for the animation to have any effect.

Comment: @Guffa how do I reset the animation?

Comment: @Jimi: Set the margins to their original values.